# Git and website development workflow

Tags: git, github, web, repository, workflow

My inquiries are specific and I understand that they can be subjective; I would appreciate any input.

Here's what I was doing before git:

- I run a PHP/MYSQL website
- I develop locally and test on WAMP
- I FTP to a staging site dev.mywebsite.com
- Once I'm happy with all the changes, I FTP to the live site

When I decided to start using Git:

- I initialized a bare repo on my hosting server
- Created a post-receive hook to deploy to dev.mywebsite.com
- I cloned the dev.mywebsite.com repo to a my local dev machine
- I test code -> commit -> push to remote (dev site)

Here are my questions:

1) There are a few files that I need them to remain different on local vs remote (these are mainly config files). I am using --assume-unchanged for these files. However, I read that doing 'git reset' would undo these so my first question:
- Is there a better way to never change the config files when I push from local to remote?

2) My workflow ends with me pushing to the dev site. I am not sure how to proceed from there, and deploy my code to the live website in the most efficient and risk free way.

*3) A bonus question: Should I integrate github/bitbucket/etc.. into my workflow?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is suitable only for very small development groups and small projects without need for complicated deploy. But:

**1) Local vs Remote**

I usually keep remote versions of config files in the repository and overwrite them on local with untracked files. The config loader then searches for override but does not fail if there is none.

**2) Dev + production**

A rather easy way is that you keep a branch for development (dev) and branch for production (master). Or as many branches as you want, in fact. In the hook you get the name of pushed branch and decide on that where the new code will be copied to (in the simplest case).

The post-update hook may look like:

```
for arg in "$@"
do
  if [ "$arg" == "refs/heads/master" ]
  then
    DEST="/path/to/production"
    git --work-tree=$DEST checkout -f
  elif [ "$arg" == "refs/heads/dev" ]
  then
    DEST="/path/to/dev"
    git --work-tree=$DEST checkout -f
  fi
done
```

**3) External repository**

If you want a backup or share with the world, yes, you should :)

Comment: Thx for the answer. I'm the only dev working on the site, so this suits me. Could you plz elaborate on the 'config loader' part of answer 1?

Comment: For example, with python I use the ConfigParser. The later files provided to read method overwrite the earlier and if they don't exist nothing happens. Thus read('db.ini', 'local.ini') would load only db.ini on server where local.ini is missing...